# How to set the margin on the button I am creating in java activity?

Tags: java, android

```
        Button button = new Button(All_HomeWork_List.this);

        button.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.orange_button) );
        button.setTextSize(25);

        buttonLay.addView(button);
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LayoutParams` to set your button margins:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
 );
 params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
 yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Sorry this code is not working at the moment.